# how to add synchronization context to async test method

Tags: c#, mstest, async-await

I have Visual Studio 2012 and an asynchronous test that needs a synchronization context.
But the default synchronization context of MSTest is null.
I would like to test as running on a WPF- or WinForms-UI thread that has a synchronization context.
What's the best method to add a SynchronizationContext to the test thread ?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyTest()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull( SynchronizationContext.Current );
        await MyTestAsync();
        DoSomethingOnTheSameThread();
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the informations from Panagiotis Kanavos and Stephen Cleary, I can write my testmethods like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
      Helper.RunInWpfSyncContext( async () =>
      {
        Assert.IsNotNull( SynchronizationContext.Current );
        await MyTestAsync();
        DoSomethingOnTheSameThread();
      });
    }
```

The inner code now runs in a WPF synchronization context and handles all exceptions as used for MSTest.
The Helper method is from Stephen Toub:

```
using System.Windows.Threading; // WPF Dispatcher from assembly 'WindowsBase'

public static void RunInWpfSyncContext( Func<Task> function )
{
  if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
  var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  try
  {
    var syncCtx = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

    var task = function();
    if (task == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    var t2 = task.ContinueWith(x=>{frame.Continue = false;}, TaskScheduler.Default);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);   // execute all tasks until frame.Continue == false

    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // rethrow exception when task has failed 
  }
  finally
  { 
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` in my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) called `AsyncContext`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    Assert.IsNotNull( SynchronizationContext.Current );
    await MyTestAsync();
    DoSomethingOnTheSameThread();
  });
}
```

However, this does not fully fake a specific UI environment, e.g., `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will still be `null`. If you need that level of faking, you should use the `SynchronizationContext` implementations from the original Async CTP. It shipped with three `SynchronizationContext` implementations that could be used for testing: a general-purpose one (similar to my `AsyncContext`), one for WinForms, and one for WPF.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a custom SynchronizationContext-derived class and register it as the current context with [SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext.aspx). Read Stephen Toub's posts on "[Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx)" and "[Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps: Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/21/10259307.aspx)".

Your custom SynchronizationContext only has to override the Post method that receives callbacks for asynchronous execution. How you execute them is up to you.

The first post provides a synchronization context that stores all posted actions in a queue and a blocking loop that takes actions from the queue and executes them in a single thread.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to declare your own test method attribute where you can inject custom code in the test run. Using that you can replace the [TestMethod] attribute with your own [SynchronizationContextTestMethod] which automatically runs the test with the context set (only tested in VS2019):

```
public class SynchronizationContextTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        Func<Task> function = async () =>
        {
            var declaringType = testMethod.MethodInfo.DeclaringType;
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(declaringType);
            await InvokeMethodsWithAttribute<TestInitializeAttribute>(instance, declaringType);
            await (Task)testMethod.MethodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);
            await InvokeMethodsWithAttribute<TestCleanupAttribute>(instance, declaringType);
        };
        var result = new TestResult();
        result.Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Passed;
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            RunInSyncContext(function);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Failed;
            result.TestFailureException = ex;
        }
        result.Duration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        return new[] { result };
    }

    private static async Task InvokeMethodsWithAttribute<A>(object instance, Type declaringType) where A : Attribute
    {
        if (declaringType.BaseType != typeof(object))
            await InvokeMethodsWithAttribute<A>(instance, declaringType.BaseType);

        var methods = declaringType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
            if (methodInfo.DeclaringType == declaringType && methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<A>() != null)
            {
                if (methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(Task))
                {
                    var task = (Task)methodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);
                    if (task != null)
                        await task;
                }
                else
                    methodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);
            }
    }

    public static void RunInSyncContext(Func<Task> function)
    {
        if (function == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(function));
        var prevContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        try
        {
            var syncContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);
            var task = function();
            if (task == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            var t2 = task.ContinueWith(x => { frame.Continue = false; }, TaskScheduler.Default);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);   // execute all tasks until frame.Continue == false

            task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // rethrow exception when task has failed
        }
        finally
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevContext);
        }
    }
}
```